# C# Windows Service with log4net - Error 1053: The Service did not respond to start or control in a timely fashion

Tags: c#, windows, service, log4net

When I install my windows service I get this error when I try to re-start the service. I'm suspecting that log4net is causing some issues.  I checked the log4net log file can still continue to append, other directories exist as per installer's File System on Target Machine setup.

```
Application: SPIDFileWatcher.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException
Stack:
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32, System.String)
   at System.IO.FileSystemEnumerableIterator`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0,Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].CommonInit()
   at System.IO.FileSystemEnumerableIterator`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0,Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]..ctor(System.String, System.String, System.String, System.IO.SearchOption, System.IO.SearchResultHandler`1<System.__Canon>)
   at System.IO.Directory.EnumerateFiles(System.String, System.String, System.IO.SearchOption)
   at FileWatchingService.FileWatcher..ctor()
   at FileWatchingService.WatchService.OnStart(System.String[])
   at FileWatchingService.WatchService.OnDebug()
   at FileWatchingService.Program.Main()
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: The exception is because the directory was not found

Comment: Why do you suspect log4net is causing some issues? There is nothing in the stacktrace to suggest that.